# php not working with php.ini file on mac os x

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm running a local server on my macbook (os x 10.9.2)

I'm trying to install mcrypt and I've run into a problem that I can't add the extension to my php.ini file, because apparently my php installation doesn't use a php.ini file.

Looking at phpinfo(), I see this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File: (none)
```

In my /etc folder, a php.ini file doesn't exist. I do have a php.ini.default, but when I make a copy of that and name it php.ini, and restart apache, PHP just stops working entirely (my php code isn't interpreted and shows up when viewing the web site's source).

Is there something in the php.ini.default file I have to change before copying it to php.ini?

Edit: Upon further trial and error, I have found that if I create a blank php.ini file and restart the server, PHP runs just fine. There must be an error in php.ini.default that is killing PHP on my local server. I've tried using php.ini.default~orig too and the same problem happens. Any way to find out what is wrong with the php.ini.default file?

Edit2: Upon further random trial and error, if my php.ini only contains:

```
[PHP]
short_open_tag = On
```

PHP works. If it only contains:

```
[PHP]
short_open_tag = Off
```

PHP doesn't work. I'm so confused.

Edit3: **Oh!** The php.ini.default file had `short_open_tag = Off`, and of course I'm using short open tags everywhere. Edit2 clued me in. Wasted half a day on this. This is so embarrassing. Everything is working now.

Comment: I would just download a fresh php.ini.default and go from there.

Comment: Do you mean the default behavior without php.ini is short tags on.. and the default text in php.ini is to switch them off .. ? =)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into the missing php.ini problem on OS X 10.9 or 10.10:

I ran into the same problem after trying install the latest php through homebrew. Turns out mac comes with php already installed, but no config file. Homebrew won't overwrite the system php binary, which remains the default.

Try `sudo rm /usr/bin/php` then `brew install homebrew/php/php55`.